# It's possible to define an default ID to a composite component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

It's possible to define a default ID for an composite component created with `<ui:component>`?

Even if I set the ID in `<ui:component>`, when the component is rendered in the page, it isn't using the defined ID and the children that descend from it have an auto generated ID  instead of the defined id.

```
<ui:component 
    id="companySearch"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>     
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify it in the `id` attribute of the component tag declaration.

```
<my:compositeComponent id="companySearch" ... />
```

The composite component is namely a [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) which allows that it can be used multiple times in the same view without that its children with a fixed ID would cause "duplicate component ID" errors. `NamingContainer` components prepend their ID to the ID of the children.

Comment: Yes, in this way it works, but there isn't a way to use an predefined/default id if the id is not set in the component tag declaration?